# Efficent ways to lure animals

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Are there any items in the Direwolf20 pack that allow you to lure animals into your farm more efficiently than by vanilla means?

Comment: Does the pack has MFR? I never played this specific pack, but MFR has some usefull stuff for moving mobs/animals.

Comment: @Arperum No it hasn't.

Comment: In that case I can't help you, sorry. MFR has a safari net that can be used for this, I don't think there is anything else.

Comment: More efficiently than leads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some effective ways to lure/move animals:

- Portalgun and gravity gun will let you pick up the animal 1 at a time.
- Drop them in a portalgun portal for fast transport over long
  distances.
- Mystcraft portal for bulk transfer/go over dimensions.
- Golden lasso will store the animal inside of it.